# Touch Manipulated Element keep behind other elements

Tags: wpf

I'm currently playing with touch gesture support and I wired up an element that can be zoomed in, rotated, etc through manipulationdelta. The elements container is a border however whenever i gesture the element it moves across the screen and I want to keep it inside the border where they can only use that area of the screen to manipulate the element. Any ideas as to how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Seeing how nobody has replied, I'll just say I think I've come up with a workaround by hosting a window inside a grid... that way the manipulation is always bound to the child window.

Comment: Nobody has any ideas? I've been struggling with this all morning now, trying to set z-indexes but still not luck. The Grid is a 2x2 matrix and the idea is to keep the manipulated element within one of those quadrants. Is this even possible?